# multithread pixel plotting lib for python

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, pixel

I am doing a graphics project and have to use pixel plotting function only. I came across pygame but it doesnt seem to provide its calls to be used in threads. Please suggest me workaround this or any other python library that can be used with threads.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import threading
import time

    class plotterthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,screen,queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.screen = screen
        self.__queue__ = queue
        self._colorset = False
        self.kill = False

    def setcolor(self,r,g,b):
        self._r = r
        self._g = g
        self._b = b
        self._colorset = True

    def run(self):
        try:
            while not self.__queue__.empty() and not self.kill:
                (x,y) = self.__queue__.get(timeout=1)
                if not self._colorset:
                                    #this is where error occures
                                    #this calls pygame.set_at() method
                    self.screen.plotpixel((x,y))

                else:
                    self.screen.plotpixel((x,y),(self._r,self._g,self._b))
        except:
            pass


class plotter:
    def __init__(self,screen,min,max,queue,ppt=50):
        self.screen = screen
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self.ppt = ppt # pixels per thread
        self.coords = queue



    def plot(self):
        noOfcoords = self.coords.qsize()
        noOfthreads = int(noOfcoords/self.ppt)
        if noOfthreads > self.max:
            noOfthreads = self.max
        elif noOfthreads < self.min:
            noOfthreads = self.min

        self.threadpool = []
        for i in range(noOfthreads):
            pthread = plotterthread(screen = self.screen,queue = self.coords)
            self.threadpool.append(pthread)
            pthread.start()


        while True:
            try:
                livethreads = 0
                for t in self.threadpool:
                    if t is not None and t.isAlive():
                        livethreads += 1
                        t.join(timeout=1)
                if livethreads == 0:
                    break
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                for threads in self.threadpool:
                    if threads is not None and threads.isAlive():
                        threads.kill = True
                break
```

Here, screen is the instance of the window on which I am trying to draw.
queue is the Queue which contains all the calculated coordinates to be plotted.

All I wanted to do was first calculate all the pixels and push them into a queue and then share the queue with threads to plot them in parallel to speed up the process.

Comment: Which Python do you use? And then why do you need threads? Why don't you use numpy or lists? What do yoou want to build?

Comment: actually I was experimenting if I can speed up the pixel drawing process using threads..

Comment: You only need to draw a pixel about 60 times a second. It highly depends on your drawing whether this takes much time. Do you have code to show? Do you need to display the result to users while the next frame is computed?